# Получение фотографий закрытой группы через photos.get vk.api

Tags: vkontakte-api

В мануале к API написано что токен для работы photos.get не нужен. При этом метод отдает access denied. Токен который получает веб-приложение он не принимает.
Группа закрытая и открыть нельзя, но альбомы открыты. Как быть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответа так и не получил, но решил проблему добавлением к запросу токена полученного через oauth 2.0 юзера у которого есть доступ к альбомам. Мануал врет похоже.

Comment: но сейчас нет доступам к фотографиям закрытой группы.